# how to connect Android studio with TFS on windows

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs

how to connect Android studio with TFS i cant find the repository's i dont know what is missing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d93FW.png)

Comment: https://java.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/androidstudio check out

Comment: i already did but still no repository showing

Comment: Can you logon to the web interface of TFS with the server url and credentials you use in Android studio? Could it be an authentication or maybe proxy problem?

Comment: yes i can login to TFS from web browser but i cant from android studio

Comment: What's your version of TFS and android-studio? Did you have a VSTS account? If you have, you could also test if it's able to find the repository in VSTS(Team Services)

Comment: TFS 2015, android studio 3.0.1 , i don't understand how VSTS can help connecting TFS to android studio

Comment: What's the auth type on your TFS server?

Comment: @Israa Sorry for the misunderstanding, test a VSTS account is help to narrow down the issue related to your local Environment or Sever Side. If you could get the repository in VSTS successfully, the issue may related to your TFS settings/authentication. If you also lose the repository in VSTS, the issue may due to your local Android- Studio configuration or Net work setting.  Did you behind any proxy? Could you connect to TFS server successfully directly through web portal?